# Throwing an UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

So one of the method descriptions goes as follows:

> public BasicLinkedList addToFront(T data) This operation is invalid
>   for a sorted list. An UnsupportedOperationException will be generated
>   using the message "Invalid operation for sorted list."

My code goes something like this:

```
public BasicLinkedList<T> addToFront(T data) {
    try {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid operation for sorted list.");
    } catch (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid operation for sorted list.");
    }
    return this;
}
```

Is this the right way of doing this? I just printed out the message using `println()` but is there a different way to generate the message?

Comment: Better to use System.out.println(e.getMessage()); within the catch.

Comment: You throw a exception and catch it in the Catch Block! You do not catch it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't want to catch the exception in your method - the point is to let callers know that the operation is not supported:

```
public BasicLinkedList<T> addToFront(T data) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid operation for sorted list.");
}
```

Comment: But this would throw it for any incoming data. You need to single out SortedList type data (look at my answer).

Comment: Ok, reading CoderNinja's comment, is this SortedLinkedList a subclass of BasicLinkedList? If so, then the overriden method in SortedLinkedList should throw the exception.This has nothing to do with the type of T.

Comment: Yea thats what I had initially but I was putting it through some tests (so for instance i had an instance of sortedLinkedList s) and i called s.addToFront(); and it generated an error in the code and i thought i had implemented it wrong. Guess thats what im supposed to do

Answer (score 3):

You could rewrite your code to be like this

```
public BasicLinkedList<T> addToFront(T data) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    if (this instanceof SortedList) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Invalid operation for sorted list.");
    }else{
        return this;
    }
}
```

That basically accomplishes what you're asking.

Comment: Well the idea is that I have a basicLinkedList class that has an addToFront method but in my sortedLinkedList class the add method adds the node to the appropriate position based on the sorting. So addToFront cannot be called as that would potentially corrupt the sortedList. As for what i want to accomplish is merely dependent on what the question is asking. I'm not sure how I should be generating the message(through println? or through the exception itself like when u get all that red crap).